# Find the interval of $k$

Tags: functions

Given $f(x)=\frac{e^x}{x^2}-k(\frac{2}{x}+\ln(x))$, $k$ is a constant.

If $f(x)$ has two extreme points at the interval of $(0,2)$.

Then find the interval of $k$.

My approaching is:

I assume the x-coordinate of the two extreme points are $x_1$ and $x_2$, and $x_1 \lt x_2$.

$f'(x)=\frac{(x-2)(e^x-kx)}{x^3}$, then there must be $x_1$ and $x_2$ to make $f'(x)=0$

They must be the root of $e^x-kx$ ,since  $0\lt x\lt2$.

Then there must be a point bigger than $x_1$ but smaller than $x_2$ to let $e^{x_0}=k$.

So, $0\lt x_0=\ln(k)\lt2$

So the minimum value of $k$ is 1 but I do not know how to find the upper bond.

Comment: Does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I do not agree that the minimum value of $k$ is 1, and I do not follow your reasoning from 'Then there must be a point...' onwards.

A slider should help you get an idea of where the minimum and maximum lie: https://www.desmos.com/calculator
Input e^x-kx

I'll let you think about the minimum for yourself some more. For the maximum, observe that if $f(x) = e^x -kx$ then $f(2) = e^2 - 2k = 0 \implies k = \frac{1}{2}e^2$.

Comment: $1\lt k$ make sure that there is at least one solution. Because$x_1$ and $x_2$ are on the line of y=kx. So within the interval of $(x_1,x_2)$, there must be a point $x_0$ to let $e^x=k$ which are the tangent case.

Comment: $k > 1$ does not ensure a solution (as you can see with the slider). Counterexample: $k = 2$, then $e^x - 2x$ has a minimum at $x = \ln(2)$, but $2 - 2\ln(2) > 0$; the function is always positive.

Comment: Yeah, it's true... I try some numbers. k is bigger than e but I do not know why.

Comment: You correctly identified the tangent case as the deciding factor between 0 and 2 solutions.  Here $x = \ln{k}$. Suppose $k \leq e^1$. Then $x \leq 1$. But note that $e^x - kx > 0$ for $x \in (0,1]$. If not, its minimum is certainly negative. But the minimum occurs when $x = \ln{k}$, so $(k-1)\ln{k} = 0$ and so $k =1$ and $x = 0$. But this contradicts $x \in (0,1]$.